# Printing numbers in a line separated by commas

Tags: python, fibonacci

So I have this function and the following code:

```
def fib():
    first, second = 0, 1

    start = int(input("Please input the desired number "))
    for i in range(start):

        second=first+second
        first=second-first

        yield first+second

line = ""
for i in fib():
    line += str(i)
print(line)
```

What I am trying to do is print the Fibonacci numbers in a single line separated by commas. How am I going to do that?

Comment: Python 2.x or 3.x? What have you tried, and what is the problem with it? What outputs do you get, and how do they differ from what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `fib`, convert it into a list, and print the result.

```
print(list(fib()))
```

Output:

```
Please input the desired number 5
[2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

If you don't like the brackets, you can convert the list into a string and strip them off.

```
print(str(list(fib())).strip("[]"))
#output: 2, 3, 5, 8, 13
```

... But there's not really much point in doing so.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your function is a little bit wrong. You can fix it with a few changes:

```
def fib():
    first, second = 0, 1

    for i in range(start):

        second=first+second
        first=second-first

        yield first
```

You also will want to ask for user's input from outside your function:

```
start = int(input("Please input the desired number "))
```

Now, you can add the Fibonacci numbers to a list and print all of them joined by ", " when you reach the number of times the user specified.

```
line = []
line_app = line.append
fib = fib()


for i in range(start): 
    line_app(str(next(fib)))

print(", ".join(line))
```

**EDIT:**

Input 1:

```
Please input the desired number 4
```

Output 1:

```
1, 1, 2, 3
```

Input 2:

```
Please input the desired number 7
```

Output 2:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13
```

Comment: Why do `line_app = line.append`? Why not just use `line.append` directly?

Comment: It's an optimization. You can check it here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...

Comment: I don't know why so many negative votes... Nobody, except for @Kevin, left a feedback comment.

Comment: I don't think it's really necessary to optimize in this case. The program will run in 0.00001 seconds without the optimization, and 0.00000999 seconds with the optimization. You should save that kind of thing for applications where a millionth of a second is a matter of life and death, not for a fibonacci printer.

Comment: Is that your opinion about code efficiency? Save it for where a second is a matter of life and death? :) Ok, then. BTW, if the user inputs large numbers, the application won't run that fast. Try it yourself.

Comment: I downvoted you because you've got an obvious SyntaxError in your print function. I also agree with Kevin about the premature optimisation, if you need fast code then use a different language which is quicker.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Ffisegydd! Fixed the CTRL + V issue.